# Django ORM: allow strictly one field to be set (NOT NULL)

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following through table for M2M relationship:

```py
class ContentOnPage(models.Model):

    objects = ContentOnPageModelManager()

    page = models.ForeignKey('Page', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video = models.ForeignKey('Video', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    audio = models.ForeignKey('Audio', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.ForeignKey('Text', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_nbr = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

And for `video`, `audio` and `text` fields I want the following constraint - there should be strictly 1 not null value in a row. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Do you want the constraint on database or application level? There is already an answer for application level validation. A database level constraint is also possible but depends on your particular database implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it before you save your instance and raise `ValidationError` if it doesn's match your requirements:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    all_values = [self.video, self.audio, self.text]
    not_null_values = [v for v in all_values if v]
    if len(not_null_values) == 1:
        super(ContentOnPage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        raise ValidationError
```

Answer (score 0):

The `clean` method can also be overridden to check if the constrain is met:

```
#models.py
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def clean(self):
    contents = [value is not None for value in [self.video, self.audio, self.text]]
    if contents.count(True) != 1:
        raise ValidationError(_("Only one of the following fields has to be set: video, audio, text"))
```